# ElasticSearch only query nested if it exists

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this search query to find the query search term "red dog" in the root Title and Description and also match the nested comments document.

```
GET /_all/video/_search
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "multi_match":{
                  "query":"red dog",
                  "fields":[
                     "Title",
                     "Description"
                  ],
                  "type": "cross_fields",
                  "operator":"and"
               }
            },
        {
         "nested":{
                  "path":"Comments",
                  "query":{
                     "multi_match":{
                        "query":"red dog",
                        "fields":[
                            "Comments.Description",
                            "Comments.Description.folded"
                        ],
                        "type": "cross_fields",
                        "operator":"and"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately for me, comments are sometimes null when I persist them to ElasticSearch, is it possible to do some sort of "include if document exists" condition?

**Update**

I still get the same error

```
[nested] failed to find nested object under path [Comments]
```

When I try to query using exists

```
    GET /_all/video/_search
    {
       "query":{
          "bool":{
             "should":[
                {
                   "multi_match":{
                      "query":"lisa",
                      "fields":[
                         "Title",
                         "Description"
                      ],
                      "type":"cross_fields",
                      "operator":"and"
                   }
                },
                {
                   "nested":{
                      "path":"Comments",
                      "query":{
                         "filtered":{
                            "query":{
                               "match_all":{}
                            },
                            "filter":{
                               "exists":{
                                  "field":"Comments.Description"
                               }
                            }
                         }
                      }
                   }
                }
             ]
          }
       }
    }
```

My mapping for everything

```
{
   "en":{
      "mappings":{
         "video":{
            "properties":{
               "Comments":{
                  "type":"nested",
                  "properties":{
                     "Description":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "analyzer":"english",
                        "fields":{
                           "folded":{
                              "type":"string",
                              "analyzer":"folding"
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               "Description":{
                  "type":"string",
                  "analyzer":"english",
                  "fields":{
                     "folded":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "analyzer":"folding"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "Title":{
                  "type":"string",
                  "analyzer":"english",
                  "fields":{
                     "folded":{
                        "type":"string",
                        "analyzer":"folding"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

And my settings

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "folding": {
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "asciifolding"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: exists filter should do what you want.  https://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html#query-dsl-exists-filter

Comment: Mark, can you post your full mapping please.

Comment: Done, please see bottom of original post.  Also included my original settings

Comment: It may be an issue with your your mapping is defined.  I created the following gist and it runs the query without any errors (on ES 1.4.4)

https://gist.github.com/jayhilden/899112a5d0fe09c5f1e9

Comment: I've just checked an it does work on the "en" index.  It doesn't work across all indexes ("_all").  Do you know why this is? Do you need to setup a default mapping across all indices?

Comment: Do all your indexes truly have a type called "video" with a nested document in the same place?  It would seem that as you expand your use of ES that would not be true.  Perhaps you could create an alias to put all the indexes together that have a type "video" with the nested document.

Comment: I just ran

GET _aliases

And it showed I also have a marvel index.  That probably doesn't have the mapping!

Comment: Do you know how to search all user created indexes?

Comment: I think that would be a bad idea because you're going to have other indexes and other types as you expand your use of ES.  I recommend creating an alias that puts all the video related indexes together.  That keeps you free to create a new index for Elmah Error Logging or something like that.

Comment: Ahh okay because at the minute, all I have are indexes per language i.e en, de, fr.  Underneath that I am storing my video types.  If any new types came up, I planned to put them under their appropriate language.   Is this approach not sensible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had a marvel index which didn't have the mapping for my type in.  I deleted the plugin and it was fine searching across all indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is to "denormalize" your data so that you have a property that contains the count and a boolean if it exists or not. Then you can just search on those properties.

For example:

```
{
   "id": 31939,
   "hasAttachments": true,
   "attachmentCount": 2,
   "attachments": [
      {
         "type": "Attachment",
         "name": "txt.txt",
         "mimeType": "text/plain"
      },
      {
         "type": "Inline",
         "name": "jpg.jpg",
         "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
      }
   ]  
}
```