# elasticsearch query to require a match only if field exists

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am running elasticsearch version 2.3.3 (via hibernate search 5.6) using json queries.  I am doing a regular search, and I want to add a contingency. I have a field, portraitOf, that is sparsely populated, and I want to know, first if the field is populated, and if so, then the search term must be found somewhere in the field for it to be a hit.

I found this answer, but cannot understand how to adapt it to my problem: [ElasticSearch only query nested if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902339/elasticsearch-only-query-nested-if-it-exists)

This query finds wallenstein when portrait is true, but does not check the portraitOf field.

```
{  
    "query":{  
      "filtered":{  
         "query":{  
            "multi_match":{  
               "query":"wallenstein",
               "fields":[  
                  "scannedText",
                  "keyWords",
                  "portraitOf"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "bool":{  
               "must":[  
                  {  
                     "term":{  
                        "portrait":"true"
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This query returns results, but accepts entries that do not contain portraitOf and entries that do not have wallenstein in the portraitOf field.

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "multi_match":{
                  "query":"wallenstein",
                  "fields":[
                     "scannedText", "keyWords","portraitOf"
                  ],
                  "type":"cross_fields",
                  "operator":"and"
               }
            },
            {
              "query":{
                 "filtered":{
                    "query":{
                       "match":{
                           "portraitOf":"wallenstein"
                       }
                    },
                    "filter":{
                       "exists":{
                          "field":"portraitOf"
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

And as I tinker around, here is a query that returns matches only when portraitOf exists and wallenstein is present in portraitOf.  But, to reiterate, what I want is, portrait is true, and wallenstein is in portraitOf only when portraitOf exists!

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "multi_match":{
                  "query":"wallenstein",
                  "fields":[
                     "scannedText", "keyWords","portraitOf"
                  ],
                  "type":"cross_fields",
                  "operator":"and"
               }
            },
            {
                "query":{
                    "filtered":{
                        "query":{
                            "match":{
                                "portrait":"true"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            {
              "query":{
                 "filtered":{
                    "query":{
                       "match":{
                           "portraitOf":"wallenstein"
                       }
                    },
                    "filter":{
                       "exists":{
                          "field":"portraitOf"
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527498/elasticsearch-bool-query-that-checks-if-property-is-missing-entirely-or-propert